# Second activity is still start on handler although press back button for quiting app

Tags: android-activity, handler

My application has an Introduce activity that show process bar before using app.

```
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loader); 

        final Handler h = new Handler() {
              @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                Intent it = new Intent(FirstIntroActivity.this, SecondIntroActivity.class); 
                it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(it);
              }     
        };
        h.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 3000);
```

But after I press **BACK** button to exit application, my phone is turn back to application and go to **SECOND** activity ( after 3000ms ). How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative is to use a Timer to schedule start of your second activity.we can cancel starting the second activity by cancelling timer in OnBackPressed() callback.

```
private Timer timer;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // add code to start your second activity
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    timer.cancel();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```